# compilation of libxcb-1.9 in ubuntu required for vlc-2.2.6 building in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vlc

I am trying to build vlc-2.2.6 in ubuntu, it gives me the below error

> checking for XCB_COMPOSITE... no configure: error: Package
>   requirements (xcb-composite) were not met: No package 'xcb-composite'
>   found Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if
>   you installed software in a non-standard prefix. Alternatively, you
>   may set the environment variables XCB_COMPOSITE_CFLAGS and
>   XCB_COMPOSITE_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config. See the
>   pkg-config man page for more details.

Hence donwloaded libxcb-1.9 and trying to build, which throws the below compilation error

Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory

```
`/home/tel/kirthika/libxcb-1.9/src'
 /usr/bin/python ./c_client.py -p /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
 /usr/local/share/xcb/sync.xml
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "./c_client.py", line 2925, in <module>
module.generate()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xcbgen/state.py", line 106, in generate
 item.out(name)
 File "./c_client.py", line 2788, in c_request
_c_type_setup(self, name, ('request',))
 File "./c_client.py", line 338, in _c_type_setup
_c_type_setup(field.type, field.field_type, ())
 File "./c_client.py", line 413, in _c_type_setup
_c_serialize('serialize', self)
 File "./c_client.py", line 1171, in _c_serialize
 count = _c_serialize_helper(context, self, code_lines, temp_vars, prefix=prefix)
 File "./c_client.py", line 1045, in _c_serialize_helper
space, prefix)
 File "./c_client.py", line 690, in _c_serialize_helper_switch
 bitcase_expr = _c_accessor_get_expr(b.type.expr, None)
 File "./c_client.py", line 1417, in _c_accessor_get_expr
 lenexp = _c_accessor_get_length(expr, field_mapping)
 File "./c_client.py", line 1394, in _c_accessor_get_length
 lenfield_name = expr.lenfield_name
 AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lenfield_name'
 make[1]: *** [sync.c] Error 1
 make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/tel/kirthika/libxcb-1.9/src'
 make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Please help me solve it

Comment: Ubuntu already contains vlc 2.2.6: https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/vlc . Use `apt install vlc`.

Comment: I'm actually trying to compile and debug VLC source code to understand playback using VAAPI and VDPAU hwaccelerators . Hence requesting for suggestions on fixing compilation issues..